# sort json object for specific val?

Tags: javascript, json

here is my code fetching makes from db according to year in option now i want to display makes alphabetically. I have tried sort() function but nothing will happened please help .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //on change year change makes
  $('#years').change(function () {
    $('#makes').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#makes').empty();
    $('#makes').append($("<option></option>")
                       .attr("value", 0)
                       .text("Select Makes"));
    $.get('index.php?route=common/custom_search/get_makes_ajax&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
          function (json) {
      if (json) {
        $.each(json, function (key, val) {
          $('#makes')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", key)
                    .text(val));
          console.log(json);
        });
        $('#makes').removeAttr("disabled");
        //               console.log(json);
      } else {
        console.log('this is not working!');
      }

    });
    $('#models').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#sub_models').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#engines').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#parts').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#search_button').attr("disabled",true);
  });
}
```

Comment: i have try val.sort(); json,sort();

Comment: json code is 
  public function get_makes_ajax(){
            $json = $this->ajax_get_makes();
            $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }

Comment: Could you provide a sample JSON please, and some rules/guide on how you want it sorted

Comment: private function ajax_get_makes(){
            $this->load->model('common/custom_search');
            $makes_list = $this->model_common_custom_search->get_all_makes();
            $result = array();
            foreach($makes_list as $make){
                $result[$make['make_id']] = $make['make_name'];
            }
            return $result;
        }

Comment: i want to sort my makes alphabetically in option

Comment: provide hard coded json

Comment: In order a sort function to work in your case, you would need to pass a comparing function. I'm assuming your JSON is an array of objects with identical properties, therefore you need to figure out by which property you want to sort them, and then use them in the compare function.
Long Story Short please provide a sample JSON.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're trying to sort an object similar to this one:

```
var json = {
      id1: 1998,
      id2: 1975,
      id3: 1983
    };
```

You can't use the sort() function on an object, so you'll have to recode your data as an array. More specifically, it will become an array of objects.

```
var arr = [];

Object.keys(json).forEach(function(id) {
  arr.push({ id: id, year: json[id] });
});
```

We now can sort `arr` (here in chronological order):

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.year - b.year; });
```

Finally, you'd need to slightly modify your code to use `arr` instead of `json`:

```
$.each(arr, function (key, val) {
  $('#makes')
    .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", val.id)
            .text(val.year));
});
```

Comment: great it works for. i used 
arr.sort( function( a, b ) {
             a = a.make.toLowerCase();
                b = b.make.toLowerCase();

              return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
           });

Comment: will you please tell me why it is not working with chrome it given an error  Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function. Please help me i am new

Comment: @dua Please see my updated answer which doesn't use `Object.values()` anymore. (This is an [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), not well-supported method, and we don't really need it anyway.)